# Change "text" property of all buttons on form incrementally

Tags: c#, arrays, button

I have created a soundboard in Visual C# where I click buttons and it plays an MP3 file. I currently have buttons named `SBut_01` to `SBut_x` appropriately.

I store paths to the MP3 files that are being associated to these buttons in an xml file, which is fed in on startup and all "captions" for the corresponding buttons (which are extracted from the path for each key) are stored in an array named `ButtonCapts[x]`.

An example of something that could be in `ButtonCapts[1]` would be `Foo` stored as a string.

Originally when I created this soundboard, I manually specified each button's caption using a method I named `AssignButtonCaptions`. Which worked crudely like so:

```
public void AssignButtonCaptions{
SBut_01.Text = ButtonCapts[1];
SBut_02.Text = ButtonCapts[2];
...
}
```

However, as this soundboard expands in scope this is becoming a **very** large section of hardcode, so I would like to automate this as much as possible.

I've thought that I could probably use a `foreach` loop in the instance of `ButtonCapts[]`, but I don't at present know a way to loop through all of my `SBut_xx` buttons. Is it possible to detect all buttons on a form that are prefixed by `SBut_` and iterate through them from 1 to x?

It would be great if something like below could be accomplished. Please note that I have assumed that each button has been put in an array named `SButList` as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I understand there is no way this code would work in its current form and am not even sure if objects such as buttons could be stored in such a way:

```
//Some kind of method to put all buttons prefixed with SBut_ in to an array named ButtonList here
    
//Then, iterate through all of the buttons and assign the captions

int i = 1;
foreach (button SBut in ButtonList)
{
   SBut.Text = ButtonCapts[i];
   i++;
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: `someControl.Controls.OfType<Button>()` should give you all the buttons on the control `someControl`. If needed you could additionally filter for specific names by adding a where clause `.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("someText"))`

Comment: Ahh, I see. That helps a lot! That helps isolate all of the buttons I need based on their name, so thank you for that. Do you perhaps know of a way that I could store all returned buttons in to an array or something similar like the example above so that I can iterate through them?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've figured this out with some help from Anu6is. I'll document what I found so that it may help others.

Turns out that you can easily extract all controls in a form by using the following to accomplish this:

```
var myButtons in Controls.OfType<Buttons>().Where(button => button.Name.Contains("Something"))
```

The issue I was having was that I needed to iterate through each parent directory, as my buttons were inside of a Group Box, which was in turn inside of one of many Tab Pages within a Tab Control object. I just did a quick `foreach` loop to iterate through all of these tabs and group boxes in order to resolve this.

My new working code looks like this, which in my opinion is much better:

```
public void AssignButtonCaptions()
        {
            foreach (TabPage Page in tabControl1.TabPages)
            {
                foreach(GroupBox ButtonContainer in Page.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
                {
                    foreach (var SButton in ButtonContainer.Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(button => button.Name.Contains("SBut")))
                    {
                        int ButtonNum = Int32.Parse(SButton.Name.Split('_')[1]);
                        SButton.Text = ButtonCapts[ButtonNum];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```